# Position left-floated elements at the center of the page

Tags: css, html, layout

I have the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/fbwv8jhp/
with the following styles:

```
.menus {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu{
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here, menu elements are aligned to left. But the additional desired behavior is to make sure that regardless the screen width (i.e. the quantity of menu divs shown in each row), they are displayed at the center. This means that in each row the distance between left menu and left screen border and right menu and right screen border should be the same, and all menus centered.
Couldn't make it, so maybe someone knows how this can be achieved.

On the image below, distances 1 and 2 should be equal.

[image: Position at center]

Comment: yes with flexbox. In order for your `margin: auto;` on your `.menus` style to work the way you want you would need to set a static width on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css flex-box:

```
.menus {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu{
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if we have uneven number of menus, for example five, it is visible that the elements in the second row are displayed in the center and not on the left.